# Should there be a [proof-writing] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I was recently reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50736/homework-one-question) and I edited it because I thought that it should have a better fitting title and tags. However, I can think of no fitting tag, as the question is not about any particular bit of math but rather about the presentation of a proof. Should there be a [proof-writing] tag, not for the methods of a proof but rather about what to include in a proof?

I'm not even sure that I think that question above belongs on this site. But maybe this tag is a good one?

Comment: I've seen many people use the proof-theory tag for this, which is definitely wrong. I would support a proof-writing tag for this purpose.

Comment: Given the lack of answers, the +1/-1 neutrality on the subject, I've decided to try it out. We'll see how it works.